# Bias Variance tradeoff in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, kernel-trick, large-data, bias-variance-tradeoff

<s>Large neural networks have low bias and high variance. Training on large datasets greatly reduces the variance allowing them to fit complicated functions. My question is why they seem to have much lower bias than other machine learning models, regardless of how flexible you make the other models.</s> *

[It's purported](https://youtu.be/PySo_6S4ZAg?t=344) that if you plot amount of data vs performance, neural networks tend to not to plateau as quickly. One could argue that this has something to do with being a universal function approximator, but this apparently applies to [other models](https://youtu.be/Vsl0x2fqdEo?t=1702) like kernel methods as well.

[image: Data vs Performance]
(from https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Performance-Comparison-of-Deep-learning-based-algorithms-Vs-Traditional-Algorithms_fig1_338027948)

What about neural networks makes them especially good at working in regimes with large amounts of data compared to more traditional models which can also be made to be arbitrarily flexible?

I can only speculate it might have something to do with the following (but I can't find definitive sources):

- weaker inductive bias
- real-world data (distribution of images, language, etc.) being particularly amenable to NN operations
- having intermediate/hierarchical representations representations is somehow important (Yann LeCun [talks about](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/yann-lecun_yann-lecun-activity-6931321709572603904-Mj3v) a Kuhnian [or Le-Kuhnian? x)] paradigm shift on this point among researchers).

*[EDIT thanks for comments - framing in terms of bias variance is murky because it's not clear how much of the performance improvement could be attributed to lower variance due to the [double descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_descent) phenomenon].

Comment: This is still an open research area.

Comment: "If you plot amount of data vs performance, neural networks tend to not to plateau as quickly. " can you give a source for that?

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Andrew Ng usually mentions it in his intro lectures https://youtu.be/PySo_6S4ZAg?t=344

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.02355

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08286

Comment: @Galen that effect described by the MSc thesis sounds a bit like this question [Is ridge regression useless in high dimensions (
n≪p
)? How can OLS fail to overfit?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328630) where adding more parameters had a regularizing effect. Another resemblance is with gradient boosting. Having more hidden units, increasing the width of the network, is like running more models in parallel.

Comment: @efthimio just because someone says something (even Andrew Ng) doesn't mean it is true.  I doubt it is without any foundation, but I suspect it is true for some subset of problems where deep learning actually works, and therefore is the subset of problems for which some results are available.  ML needs to start being interested in proper benchmarking and evaluation.  BTW years ago I took part in a challenge on large scale ML, ITSR I did reasonably well using linear regression, not the best, but certainly not the worst.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, what does ITSR stand for?

Comment: I Seem To Recall, but TITMH (Typed In Too Much Haste) ;o)

Comment: @DikranMarsupial It's parroted in other places (e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338027948_A_deep_learning_methods_for_intrusion_detection_systems_based_machine_learning_in_MANET). Let me know if you have contrary evidence - it's your word against his, but evidence is king above you both.

Comment: @efthimio I don't have a word, I was just speaking in favour of skepticism. Things being "parroted" is exactly the problem. If I did have a word it was " ML needs to start being interested in proper benchmarking and evaluation." i.e. lets have some actual evidence rather than diagrams and assertions.   I don't disagree with Andrew Ng, I just suspect there is some qualification required on the applicability of the assertion.

Comment: I think you are right - “parroting” is a problem. For example, if “double descent” overturns prior wisdom about bias-variance, then it’s stunning to me it was discovered so late. Did no one train highly overparameterized models before the 2010s because convention told them not to? But to defend my original point, it is precisely for this reason I asked the question in the first place - I’ve got diagrams and assertions from reputable people, but I wanted to know if anyone in the community could back it up.

Comment: "Did no one train highly overparameterized models before the 2010s" no, we did *plenty* of that! ;o)

Comment: Perhaps the more precise question is "Did no one try to plot model capacity vs model performance before the Belkin et al paper"? They present it as a robust finding, applying to not just NNs but also tree-based models. They have a brief section trying to explain the "Historical Absence" of the finding, but IMO it's not enough to counterbalance the weight of the historical consensus it tries to overturn.

Answer (score 8):

The existence of a bias-variance tradeoff has been assumed as inevitable (i.e., an axiom) in any model using data, including neural networks.

However, it has been observed since about 2018 that surprisingly, **some** cases of very large deep neural networks, trained with a correspondingly sufficiently large dataset, do not exhibit the classical bias-variance tradeoff. This means that these networks also generalize better. This phenomenon, termed "**double descent**", has been duplicated by other researchers. See for example:
"Reconciling modern machine-learning practice and the classical bias–variance trade-off", 2019, by Belkin, Hsu, Ma, Mandal, https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1903070116.

As of 2022, conclusively explaining this phenomenon is still an open research question, but there have recently been interesting inroads to answering it. For example, the following paper is a theoretical explanation to justify this mysterious phenomenon:
"A Universal Law of Robustness via Isoperimetry", 2021, by Bubeck and Sellke, https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.12806 (Outstanding Paper award at NeurIPS 2021)

- The analysis/explanation is based on a network having a small
  Lipschitz constant (maximum value of the gradients), meaning the
  function represented by the network is smooth.
- The paper also claims that in addition to good generalization, such a
  phenomenon also implies better robustness to adversarial attacks.
- The analysis is not limited to neural networks, but is
  general enough for many other function approximations (including Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space).
- The paper gives specific guidance on the number of parameters vs. the
  amount of data for this phenomenon to occur.

Emphasis: This "double descent" phenomenon does **not** occur in **all** deep neural networks trained with a correspondingly sufficiently large dataset. Rather, according to Bubeck and Sellke, it depends on the number of input data points, the effective dimension of the classification, the depth of the network (number of layers), and the overall number of parameters in the network.

Therefore, in other cases, neural networks, even deep ones, will still exhibit the bias-variance tradeoff.

In a sense, this guidance on parameter values in the Bubeck and Sellke paper can be regarded as a falsifiable prediction as to whether their analysis/explanation is (in)correct.

Comment: Is this related to the “self-regularization” that I’ve heard mentioned?

Comment: @Dave regarding "self-regularization": I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure. self-regularization includes early stopping and various batch size tricks during training. These are inherent to neural networks, but the explanation/analysis by Bubeck and Sellke is based on smoothness in the very high-dimensional parameter space of the network around each input data vector (when such smoothness exists).

Comment: Great citations. This muddies my attempt to frame the question in terms of bias-variance. I had said that NN bias was lower, but past the "interpolation threshold" the improvement might as well be attributed to a reduction in variance - it's now unclear to me. Thanks for enlightening :)

Though these papers explore a novel phenomenon, they don't make decisive claims about why NNs reliably do better (in fact, both show how this particular novelty applies to other models, making the distinction murkier). Are there authoritative sources saying it's unsolved? I put speculations in my question

Comment: @efthimio I've added an important emphasis to my answer, that in other cases, neural networks, even deep ones, will still exhibit the bias-variance tradeoff. As I currently understand, the Bubeck and Sellke paper analysis/explanation is not fully accepted yet (I've added to my answer the falsifiable prediction implied by their paper), therefore, the problem is not accepted as "solved". Some problems in machine learning cannot be proved as true or false as in other parts of mathematics or computer science, perhaps this is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Bias-variance trade-off is an old fashioned concept from classical statistics which fails to be useful in high-dimensional setting.

Here's an example of famous statistician being [surprised](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08560) that overfitting is reduced by increasing the number of parameters in linear regression.

A better way to explain good performance of neural networks is through the lens of statistical learning theory. One direction of work shows that if A) your learner is not very sensitive to small changes in your training set, and B) fits training data data it will also fit test data. See for instance, this [paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume2/bousquet02a/bousquet02a.pdf) by Bousquet.

Hastie's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08560) shows that adding parameters restricts final solution to a smaller L2-norm ball, hence improving stability A). At the same time, adding parameters can improve training fit, hence improving B).

B) is actually the harder part, much of modern progress in NN's has been achieved by coming up with clever ways of fitting the training data and ignoring generalization aspect.

Comment: (+1) nice references.

Answer (score 0):

There are other theorems in mathematical analysis about converging to decent functions (the Stone–Weierstrass theorem about polynomials and Carleson's theorem about Fourier series come to mind). However, neural networks decrease the bias more than other regression models by taking to the extreme the idea of nonlinearity and interaction. A neural network with millions of parameters is routine. A generalized linear model with millions of parameters, due to nonlinear basis functions (e.g., polynomials or splines) and their interactions, is not as common. If you put in all of those nonlinear features and their interactions in a generalized linear model, taking it to a similar extreme as a neural network, I would expect similar issues of high variance and low bias.

In fact, there is a sense in which a neural network (at least some of them) involves a layer (or multiple layers) of feature extraction and then a generalized linear model on the extracted features. After all, if you draw out the usual "web" of a neural network and cover up everything before the final hidden layer, you wind up with something that looks like a generalized linear model.

Comment: What do we mean by “taking to the extreme the idea of nonlinearity”? Also, framing in terms of GLMs is not so helpful because as you alluded to, you can compose them to make something that is practically a neural network. But why don’t Random Forests work as well with large data? Why don’t cubic splines?

Comment: @efthimio When you have a million parameters (potentially many more) in a neural network, you can bend the regression line in almost any way.  // Framing in terms of GLM is helpful specifically because they can be wrestled with to form universal approximators like neural networks are. // I do not know of any convergence theorems for random forests (they might exist, but they might not), but including a bunch of spline terms and interactions between them is basically what a neural network is doing. Neural networks just throw millions of parameters at the problem, rather than dozens.

Comment: I think spline is different because it is non-parametric. These models become more flexible as you add more data - it would make sense that these would be similarly effective as neural networks but I don't hear them being used.

Comment: It depends on what you consult. Splines come up on here all the time. Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* book covers splines early, and he emphasizes the use of splines all the time.

Comment: Is this an unsolved problem? Is it because of hardware optimized now for NNs? I feel like if there was a convergence theorem for random forests, it would confuse matters further because they don't get SOTA results for language and vision tasks that require huge datasets. Likewise for splines - you argue they are effective but they aren't breaking all the benchmarks.

Comment: Dave, what would be your take on the question of why it is specifically neural networks that seem to be all the rage these days? Quoting the OP, *I want to know whether neural networks are taking off more because historical happenstance (e.g. we have hardware optimized for them, it is easy to extend their flexibility, etc) or because there is something theoretically interesting about them which other machine learning models lack.*

Comment: @RichardHardy I’m as puzzled as anyone about why neural network function approximation is the rage right now. I wonder if some of it is that people forget about nonlinear basis functions in generalized linear models. I recently saw a presentation where that seemed to be the case. Some of it also could be that using a modern and fancy-sounding technique might make it easier to publish in academia or charge a high rate in industry.

Answer (score -1):

#### Sidenote: It depends on the situation

The question is a bit of a loaded question. It presupposes that neural networks are better. But, whether neural networks are better depends on the situation. If parametric models are applicable, then often these will work better. If the data generation doesn't follow a complex pattern (so nothing specific for a deep neural network to learn), then often the other shallow machine learning methods work better.

But still, the question is a fair question. The observation that over-parameterized models perform surprisingly good in particular settings, without overfitting (and whether this is only with neural networks or not is actually not relevant), that is not something unreal.

#### Flat vs Deep

The relationship between deep neural networks and other more shallow machine learning methods (shallow could be kernel methods or decision trees, but they can also be very complicated), is like the relationship between Copernicus model of the solar system and Ptolemy's model of the solar system.

- In some way, the kernel methods and decision trees are like glorified methods for smoothening or averaging of data. There is no strong connection with any simple underlying process or patterns that may create the observations. The methods are only superficially learning how to be able to describe the observations in a way that it can be interpolated or extrapolated with a sufficient accuracy. If you add more data the methods gain some precision for the area where the data has been added, but their learning capacity stagnates because the models never gain a 'higher level of understanding' of the patterns or some break down of the complexity of the observations into simple building blocks.
- On the other hand, the deep neural networks are sort of like applying [Occam's razor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) and bring the complex gamut of observations down to a simplified underlying principle, which is captured by the organization of the network (and with every extra network layer the possibilities grow multiplicative increasing the potential complexity and rate of simplifying power). The neural network tries to learn the observation by learning a pattern behind it.

#### Double descent phenomenon

The over-parameterized networks are susceptible to fitting noise, but the simplest patterns are easier to learn and will become dominant. This is either due to some explicit [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) (obvious in ridge regression or Lasso) or due to some implicit regularization like limits on learning rates and stochastic decent. In this respect an example that *more* parameters work better is seen in this question: [Is ridge regression useless in high dimensions ($n \ll p$)? How can OLS fail to overfit?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328630/).

Another effect could be that the multiple parameters work a bit like [gradient boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) and are being blended together. When we spèeak about gradient boosting then there are also a lot of parameters fitted, more than the number of data points, but the method uses some average and we consider it not really as increasing the flexibility. This can happen in some similar way in deep neural networks and the first layers create several parallel pattern recognition models that are blended together in other layers.

Comment: Why the -1? A constructive comment explaining that would be welcome.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I would say that neural networks are the antithesis of Occam's razor!  In general the learned representations are distributed and highly redundant - far from simple.  IIRC very large neural networks have been shown to be equivalent to Gaussian Processes, which are Bayesian kernel methods.  Kernel machines are mostly very similar to RBF neural networks.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I didn't mean with Occam's razor that neural networks are simple. But what the neural networks can do is perform the classification by mimicking structures created by the *underlying* simple principles of the data generating process. You start with a big network and require this network to organise, the process of this organisation is sort of like applying Occam's razor. By adding more data the network will learn to adapt to the simple underlying principle (that's when it is not effectively like a Gaussian Process).

Comment: It sounds a bit paradoxical; by being complex the neural network can be able simple. To be able to (flexibly) capture a simple underlying process behind some complex dataset, the model should allow a way for a simple process to create complex relationships.

Comment: Are RBF neural networks large neural networks?

Comment: " mimicking structures created by the underlying simple principles of the data generating process."  I don't think that is actually true.  They generate "features" that can be used to minimise the cost function, but that doesn't mean that they necessarily represent features of the data generating process.

Comment: You can build an RBF neural network as large as you like.  Kernel methods have one RBF node per training pattern.  For a big dataset, that is a very large network.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial but then those RBF networks are large, but not deep networks. Could we not possibly design some kernel methods in some way that they are equal to a single layer neural network?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus not all neural networks are deep, and deep neural networks are not always a good thing (I've recently been working on a task where they get soundly beaten by multinomial logistic regression).  Neural nets (including deep ones) are Gaussian processes when they are very wide.  Most standard kernel methods are equivalent to shallow neural networks (but with no local minima), but there are also deep formulations of kernel methods as well.  A lot of this is hype rather than substance - we don't hear about the failures.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I am not sure that they will exactly mimic the data generating process, but they *can* generate complexity by a simple combination of nodes. With several layers this complexity grows. When you let the network crystallize then you automatically get that the simpeler efficiënt modes will grow.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus they won't necessarily mimic the data generating process *at all*, the internal representations form by minimising a cost function - if they match the data generating process is a happy accident, but often they don't..

Comment: When networks are shallow and the growth is just in the width, then I guess that the same applies to the neural network that it will plateau. And sure other methods can do better, it depends on the task (but that does not explain *why* neural networks perform better when they do).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus " I guess that the same applies to the neural network that it will plateau." do you have a citation for that?  Personally I think the reason neural networks work well is that "good" local minima are easy to find, which is somewhat ironic as local minima used to be viewed as a disadvantage.

Comment: BTW shallow neural networks can be surprisingly resistant to overfitting (even without regularisation), which I found in a study I did over a decade ago (pre relu etc.) and couldn't get published because it wasn't seen as interesting at the time https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw/2334#2334

Comment: I don't have a good reference/citation but it is in this graph that you see across many places on the internet https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44768/learning-capacity-deep-learning-vs-traditional-shallow-learning (also shown in the video of Andrew Ng linked by efthimio) the 'size' relates more to the 'depth'. In some places the labels are also replaced like here https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Performance-Comparison-of-Deep-learning-based-algorithms-Vs-Traditional-Algorithms_fig1_338027948/amp

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus cheers, I'm a bit resistant to schematic drawings without studies to back them up, but if they are from Andew Ng that is better than most!  ML is a terrible field for proper empirical studies and for getting carried away with enthusiasm!

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I think you might want to include citations - the recent bounty emphasized "answer from a reputable source". In my own opinion, the statements here are not precise. Can you *score* how much a model conforms to Occam's razor (and do you observe NNs have the highest "score")? Why doesn't the phrasing "simplify down to a simplified underlying principle" apply to other models? You say that other models *only* summarize whereas NNs "learn a pattern". What is the difference? Boosted tree models routinely outperform NNs in Kaggle - is this unaccountable in your view?

Comment: @efthimio the comparison with Occam's razor is incredibly based on intuition. I have no citations for this. But I guess we all at least intuitively understand why a network with multiple layers is able to capture more complexity than a network with only a few layers and is able to perform certain tasks better. From that point it is only a small step to also understand, at least intuitively, how deep networks also learn *differently*.

Comment: Can you score this or quantify this? That I don't know. Sometimes it seems more like art than science. Why do NN not always work better (like on kaggle)?  I am not saying in my answer that NNs are (always) better. It's a false preconception in the question to state that NNs are better. It depends on the task. And also like Dikran Marsupial commented, the non-neural network techniques can also have some depth.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Could I have a reference for the paper/book showing equivalence between large NN's and Gaussian processes? I'd like to better understand the assumptions, which equivalence relation, and whether the proof is asymptotic (if so, also the rate of convergence).

Comment: @Galen I think "Priors for infinite networks" by Radford Neal (1994) was the paper I was thinking of

Comment: Relating to the last posts on *"equivalence between large NN's and Gaussian processes"* I imagine a similar relationship between neural networks and decision trees when the activation functions are step functions. The difference is that neural networks can be organized differently and may contain multiple layers.