# Ridge regression / regularization approach to hierarchical model

Tags: multilevel-analysis, ridge-regression, regularization

Suppose we observe panel data
$$y_{it} = \alpha_i + \beta_i\,t + \epsilon_{it}$$
where $i$ indexes organizations, $t$ is time, and $\epsilon_{it}$ is i.i.d noise.  The terms $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are organization-specific constants and organization-specific time trends, respectively.

A simple approach to estimating $\{\alpha_i\}$ and $\{\beta_i\}$ would be to run a simple linear regression for each organization (no pooling). Suppose instead that we want to shrink our estimates of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ toward some central value (partial pooling). We could solve
$$\min_{\hat{\alpha}, \, \hat{\beta}, \, \{\hat{\alpha}_i\}, \{\hat{\beta}_i\}} \sum_{it} \left(y_{it} - \hat{y}_{it}\right)^2 + \lambda^{(\alpha)}\sum_i \left(\hat{\alpha}_i - \hat{\alpha}\right)^2 + \lambda^{(\beta)}\sum_i \left(\hat{\beta}_i - \hat{\beta}\right)^2$$
where the predicted values $\hat{y}_{it}$ are defined as
$$\hat{y}_{it} \equiv \hat{\alpha}_i + \hat{\beta}_i \, t$$
and $\lambda^{(\alpha)}$ > 0 and $\lambda^{(\beta)}$ > 0 are regularization parameters (which could be selected to minimize e.g. root mean squared error on test data).

(Edit: I believe it is always optimal to set $\hat{\alpha}$ equal to the mean of the $\hat{\alpha}_i$, and similarly for $\hat{\beta}$, in which case the minimization can be done with respect to only $\{\hat{\alpha}_i\}$ and $\{\hat{\beta}_i\}$.)

This feels similar to a Bayesian hierarchical model or to a mixed effects model in which the $\{\alpha_i\}$ and $\{\beta_i\}$ are each drawn from a distribution (e.g. $\alpha_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_\alpha, \sigma^2_\alpha))$, and the estimates are shrunk towards a pooled mean. In the minimization problem I wrote above, the shrinkage terms should tend to shrink $\hat{\alpha}_i$ towards $\hat{\alpha}$.

My questions are

1. How does this compare to a Bayesian hierarchical model? Is my $\hat{\alpha}$ analogous to $\mu_\alpha$ when $\alpha_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_\alpha, \sigma^2_\alpha))$?
2. How does this compare to a mixed effects model?
3. Is there a closed form solution to $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$? Are they equal to the complete-pooling ordinary least squares estimates?
4. Can my minimization problem be reformulated as a standard ridge regression problem (perhaps by making the data zero-mean)?
5. Are there any references on using ridge / L2 normalization for hierarchical regressions as I do here? Is this commonly done, or am I doing something unusual?

---

Here is an R simulation of what I described above:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

params <- list('n_orgs' = 100,
               'n_years' = 8,
               'alpha' = 100.0,    # Constant
               'beta' = 5.0,       # Time trend
               'alpha_sd' = 10.0,  # Std dev of org-specific alphas (centered around params['alpha'])
               'beta_sd' = 1.0,    # Std dev of org-specific betas (centered around params['beta'])
               'epsilon_sd' = 8.0) # Std dev of iid noise

## Organizations indexed by i, time indexed by t
## Observe y_it = alpha_i + beta_i * t + epsilon_it (linear time trend plus iid noise)
## Want to shrink org-specific intercept and slope towards fully-pooled mean (if it improves prediction MSE)

get_simulation <- function(params) {
    org_ids <- seq_len(params$n_orgs)
    times <- seq_len(params$n_years)  # Make time start at 1 for simplicity (e.g. years since initial year)
    org_params <- data.frame(org_id=org_ids,
                             alpha=rnorm(n=length(org_ids),
                                         mean=params$alpha,
                                         sd=params$alpha_sd),
                             beta=rnorm(n=length(org_ids),
                                        mean=params$beta,
                                        sd=params$beta_sd))
    df <- expand.grid(org_id=org_ids, time=times)
    df <- merge(df, org_params, by='org_id')
    df$epsilon <- rnorm(n=nrow(df),
                        mean=0,
                        sd=params$epsilon_sd)
    df$y <- df$alpha + df$beta * df$time + df$epsilon
    df$org_id_string <- sprintf("org %03i", df$org_id)
    return(list(df=df,
                org_params=org_params))  # True org-specific parameters (compare to estimates)
}

simulation <- get_simulation(params)
df <- simulation$df
head(df, 20)

palette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, 'Accent'))(length(unique(df$org_id)))
p <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=y, color=org_id_string)) +
      scale_colour_manual(values=palette) +
      geom_point(size=2.0) +
      geom_line(size=1.2))
p

df_train <- subset(df, time <= params$n_year - 2)
df_test <- subset(df, time > params$n_years - 2)  # Test on two held-out years
stopifnot(nrow(df) == nrow(df_train) + nrow(df_test))
stopifnot(all(sort(unique(df_train$org_id)) == sort(unique(df_test$org_id))))  # Need same orgs in train and test set (estimated params are org-specific)

get_params_hat <- function(x, n_orgs) {
    stopifnot(length(x) == 2 * (n_orgs + 1))  # Overall (alpha, beta), plus org-specific (alpha_i, beta_i)
    alpha <- x[1]
    beta <- x[2]
    org_alphas <- x[seq(3, 2 + n_orgs)]
    org_betas <- x[seq(2 + n_orgs + 1, length(x))]
    stopifnot(length(org_alphas) == length(org_betas))
    return(list(alpha=alpha,
                beta=beta,
                org_alphas=org_alphas,
                org_betas=org_betas))
}

objective_fn <- function(x, df, params, lambda_alpha, lambda_beta) {
    params_hat_list <- get_params_hat(x, params$n_orgs)
    org_ids <- sort(unique(df$org_id))
    stopifnot(length(org_ids) == length(params_hat_list$org_alphas))
    org_params_hat_df <- data.frame(org_id=org_ids,
                                    alpha_hat=params_hat_list$org_alphas,
                                    beta_hat=params_hat_list$org_betas)
    df_params_hat <- merge(df, org_params_hat_df, by='org_id')
    df_params_hat$y_hat <- df_params_hat$alpha_hat + df_params_hat$beta_hat * df_params_hat$time
    return(sum((df_params_hat$y - df_params_hat$y_hat) ^ 2) / nrow(df_params_hat) +
           lambda_alpha * sum((params_hat_list$org_alphas - params_hat_list$alpha) ^ 2) +
           lambda_beta * sum((params_hat_list$org_betas - params_hat_list$beta) ^ 2))
}

model_unregularized <- lm(y ~ org_id_string + org_id_string:time, data=df_train)
summary(model_unregularized)
rmse_test_unregularized <- sqrt(mean((df_test$y - predict(model_unregularized, newdata=df_test)) ^ 2))

x <- c(params$alpha,
       params$beta,
       rep(params$alpha, params$n_orgs),
       rep(params$beta, params$n_orgs))  # Initial parameter values for optim
cv_grid <- expand.grid(lambda_alpha=10^seq(2, -6, -1),
                       lambda_beta=10^seq(2, -6, -1))
cv_grid$mse_test <- 0
cv_grid$rmse_test <- 0
params_hat_list <- list()
for(i in seq_len(nrow(cv_grid))) {
    optimization_result <- optim(par=x,
                                 fn=objective_fn,
                                 gr=NULL,  # TODO Gradient
                                 method='BFGS',
                                 control=list(maxit=200),
                                 df=df_train,
                                 params=params,
                             lambda_alpha=cv_grid$lambda_alpha[i],
                             lambda_beta=cv_grid$lambda_beta[i])
    params_hat <- get_params_hat(optimization_result$par, params$n_orgs)
    params_hat_list[[i]] <- params_hat
    mse_test <- objective_fn(optimization_result$par,
                             df=df_test,
                             params=params,
                             lambda_alpha=0,
                             lambda_beta=0)  # Turn off lambdas to get only MSE
    cv_grid$mse_test[i] <- mse_test
    cv_grid$rmse_test[i] <- sqrt(mse_test)
}
summary(cv_grid)

p <- (ggplot(cv_grid, aes(x=log10(lambda_alpha),
                          y=rmse_test,
                          color=log10(lambda_beta),
                          group=lambda_beta)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line() +
      geom_hline(yintercept=rmse_test_unregularized, linetype=2) +
      scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=median(log10(cv_grid$lambda_beta))))
p

p <- (ggplot(cv_grid, aes(x=log10(lambda_alpha),
                          y=log10(lambda_beta),
                          fill=rmse_test)) +
      geom_raster() +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours=terrain.colors(10)))
p  # When one lambda is large, the other should be small

cv_grid[which.min(cv_grid$rmse_test), ]
params_hat <- params_hat_list[[which.min(cv_grid$rmse_test)]]
```

Comment: I think this question has some overlap with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122062/unified-view-on-shrinkage-what-is-the-relation-if-any-between-steins-paradox

Comment: Isn't it just regular ridge regression with constant term = alpha +beta

Comment: @seanv507 Ridge shrinks towards zero, whereas here I'm shrinking the $\hat{\alpha}_i$ towards their mean. Could I achieve the same thing using a regular ridge regression (perhaps by first subtracting out the fit of an ordinary linear regression, and then running ridge on the residuals)?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but if you want to shrink to the mean alphas betas of your dataset, then this is equivalent to fitting y_i = alpha_i +   beta_i t + beta t + alpha (where alpha and beta is unregularised). [[I made a mistake above forgetting the beta being multiplied by t]... Now your beta_i is the deviation from the mean beta

Comment: @seanv507 yes, exactly. Is that commonly done? I haven't seen it before. If you have any references related to that sort of regularization (i.e. regularizing only the coefficients that are subscripted by i), could you post them in an answer?

Comment: What is typically done is not penalizing   the intercept (alpha).. however if you write it as I have, then beta Will not be penalised much since it reduces the error on all samples whereas the beta_i reduces it only for a single organisation.you can view the lambda as the mse/unit coefficient..

Comment: http://andrewgelman.com/2018/03/24/economist-wrote-asking-make-sense-fit-bayesian-hierarchical-models-instead-frequentist-random-effects/ seems relevant to this question