# Intuition behind the Stein's paradox

Tags: estimation, decision-theory, regularization

I had read wiki and some sources. 
[jmanton's blog](http://jmanton.wordpress.com/2010/06/05/comments-on-james-stein-estimation-theory/),
[Wasserman's blog](http://normaldeviate.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/steins-paradox/)

---

the background is that:

You have Xi ∼ N(θi, 1), and we want to estimate the each θi.
Where Xi are `independent`。

For `MSE` risk of vector (X1,...,Xn), when n>=3.

- the MLE estimator $\hat θ_i = x_i$ is inadmissable .
- While James-Stein estimator is better than MLE in such case.

---

### Looking from Shrinkage

quote from Larry Wasserman:

> Note that the James-Stein estimator `shrinks` {X} towards the origin. (In fact, you can shrink towards any point; there is nothing special about the origin.)

I know the James-Stein estimator is special to MLE for its shrinkage behavior.
I still dont get it, the variables are independent.

**Why James-Stein estimator `shrinkage` to arbitrary point can improve the MSE risk versus where MLE do `not shrinkage` at all ??**

---

and seeing this from Larry Wasserman:

> This can be viewed as an empirical Bayes estimator ....

If view it from Empirical Bayes case, it is shrinkage to a overall mean, but that is nonsense if you have independent variable to estimate.

---

Is there better example or intuitive explanation for it?? THANKS.

Comment: Related: [Intuition behind why Stein's paradox only applies in dimensions $\geq 3$](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/intuition-behind-why-steins-paradox-only-applies-in-dimensions-ge-3/13647#13647)

Comment: You might also be interested in the recent paper: R. Beran (2010), [The unbearable transparency of Stein estimation](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.imsc/1291044739), *IMS Collections*, vol. 7, 25-34. Of course, you'll have to forgive the author somewhat for the choice of title, though the selection was intended, I believe, to make a point.