# Lasso predictive equations

Tags: regression, prediction, lasso, bias

After estimating the Lasso coefficients in linear regression. Should we expect that prediction is unbiased ?

For example, for a new point $ (x^*,y^*)$, Should we expect $ E(y^*)=x^*\hat{\beta}$ to be unbiased ?

Under the assumption that  $\hat{\beta}$ is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (i.e. we are able to reach the global maximizer)

If it is biased, what are common corrections ?

Answer (score 1):

Lasso is a good example where bias can be actually preferable.

Take a look at this question and it's answers:

[When is a biased estimator preferable to unbiased one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207760/when-is-a-biased-estimator-preferable-to-unbiased-one)