# Interpretation of Elastic Net Regression Coefficients

Tags: regression-coefficients, lasso, regularization, elastic-net

I would like to interpret the coefficients of an elastic net regression (I'm using function `glmnet()$beta` in R).

The coefficients of the elastic net regularized regression are considered "biased" coefficients because a L1/L2 penalty was added to the cost function during the calculation.

So my question is, can these biased coefficients represent the practical significance between the predictors and the response variable? If they can't, how can I transform these coefficients into unbiased estimates?

Comment: If you want unbiased estimates of coefficients, you shouldn't use regularization

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, Thanks for the answer! My aim is to quantify the impact of every predictor to the reponse variable,  which means the result should be interpretable, then I chose the regression method. But as I have a very high dimension dataset, and some predictors are highly correlated, the elastic net regularization maybe is a good way. At the same time, my data comes from the medical domain, so we need to have a estimate which is the closest to the reality. Do you have any other suggestion for getting a unbiased estimates??

Comment: Why do you think that unbiased estimators are "closest to reality"? If regularization helps to reduce variance, those regularized estimators could well be better!

Comment: it might be helpful to look at the difference between an unbiased estimator and a low MSE estimator. I've written about it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207760/) and I know there are other places on this site that discuss it too. The basic idea is that probably you'd rather be close with your particular sample than correct when averaged over all possible samples