# Total Cost Shrinkage

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, ridge-regression, loss-functions, regularization

I have a question regarding Shrinkage Methods. I am currently writing a term paper about ridge regression and lasso and before explaining the two methods, I want to give some theory on why shrinking the coefficients can help to improve prediction results.

I found a very cool coursera course on machine learning from the University of Washington, which explains the whole concept very well. In it they used one formula for the total cost of a regression, which seems to justify using shrinkage best:

```
Total Cost = measure of fit + measure of magnitude of coefficients
```

However, the formula is not derived and I dont know why it holds. I tried to google it, but I could not find this formula anywhere else than on that course.
It seems to me that this is some kind of decomposition of the total cost function of a regression.

Does anyone have an idea how this formula is justified/derived?

Answer (score 1):

Lasso and ridge regression can be interpreted in Bayesian framework as **Maximum A Posteriori** estimation (the regularization term comes from the prior). For the details see [these notes](http://ieor.berkeley.edu/~ieor165/lecture_notes/ieor165_lec8.pdf) or first chapters of [Statistical Learning with Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity_files/SLS_corrected_1.4.16.pdf).

There is also a derivation for linear regression that is based on assuming that **predictor variables are noisy**. [Notes for Hinton's  coursera course](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec9.pdf) contain the details (Lecture 9c, Using noise as a regularizer).

Answer (score 0):

Shrinkage can improve prediction because of the bias-variance tradeoff: a small increase in bias (the penalty) in exchange for a larger reduction in variance (the model is less sensitive to noise or correlation of predictors).

Another way to motivate the expression you wrote is to consider the connection between setting a maximum size on some norm of the coefficients and an equivalent unconstrained optimization problem. See [Showing the Equivalence Between the $ {L}_{2} $ Norm Regularized Regression and $ {L}_{2} $ Norm Constrained Regression Using KKT](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401212/showing-the-equivalence-between-the-l-2-norm-regularized-regression-and)

Some related questions:

- [What problem do shrinkage methods solve?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20295/what-problem-do-shrinkage-methods-solve/20303#20303)
- [Why does shrinkage work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179864/why-does-shrinkage-work/179865#179865)
- [Intuitive explanation of the bias-variance tradeoff?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/intuitive-explanation-of-the-bias-variance-tradeoff)